# Getting error from accessing DataReader value (accessing joined table results in SqlDataReader)

Tags: asp.net, datareader

*UPDATE - PROBLEM SOLVED*

Just in case to retrieve all data at once, using a single SQL statement to retrieve joined table results, but couldn't access it and received error below

Exception details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: crsName

By the way, anyone please suggest a more convenient way to deal with a GridView that need to display a JOIN result.
Instead of this approach - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.add?view=netframework-4.8

```
BoundField courseBF = new BoundField();
courseBF.DataField="courseName";
courseBF.HeaderText="Course Name";
//Which is stated in Microsoft Document
```

Here's the code receive error

```
    string userID = (string)Session["userID"];
    string sql = "SELECT courseID from gpaSem where stuID=@userID";
    string temp = "";
    string temp02 = "";
    string[] crsID;
    string[] crsName;
    string[] grade;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userID);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        temp += ("!" + dr["courseID"]);
    }
    crsID = temp.Split('!');
    crsID = crsID.Skip(1).ToArray();//course ID get
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();

    con.Open();
    temp = "";
    foreach (string crs in crsID)
    {
        sql = "SELECT G.grade AS grade, C.crsName AS crsName FROM gpaSem G, course C WHERE G.courseID=C.courseID AND G.courseID=@courseID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseID", crs);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.Read())
        {
            temp += "!" + dr["crsName"];//error
            temp02 += "!" + dr["grade"];
        }
    }
    crsName = temp.Split('!');
    crsName = crsName.Skip(1).ToArray();//course name get
    grade = temp02.Split('!');
    grade = grade.Skip(1).ToArray();//grade get
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
```

My point is, is that I should explicitly use JOIN in SQL statement or the way I access the value is wrong?

Comment: On which line do you get the excetpion? At first glance I would say that there are at least two points in which you don't check how many rows you have retrieved and assumed that at least one is present

Comment: @Steve here it is:::       temp += "!" + dr["crsName"];//error

Comment: I see it now. The query inside the for each is never assigned to the SqlCommand.CommandText. You are repeating the first query and of course there is no field with that name in the results

Comment: But then you add the same parameter for each loop instead of just changing the values. Why don't you recreate the command outside the loop, add the parameter with an empty value and then, inside the loop, just change the parameter value?

Comment: Finally about the JOIN question. [Bad habits to kick: Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: My god, just get to know that I can access each parameter value in SqlParameterCollection like this --- cmd.Parameters["@courseID"].Value